# Building C++ and Java code using CMake and Maven and bundle in a jar

Tags: java, c++, maven, cmake

I have legacy C++ code that is built using CMake. It generates a `.so` file. I need to wrap this code in Java and build a `jar` that includes Java code as well as C++ for deployment.

Steps for building C++ code with CMake is simple:

```
cd /to/pkg/dir
cmake .
make
```

The `.so` file is generated under a `build/` directory. If I convert the whole project into maven, I will have to modify the directory structure (here is a blog post that explains how that could work: [http://blog.bigpixel.ro/2012/07/building-cc-applications-with-maven/](http://web.archive.org/web/20170925192955/http://blog.bigpixel.ro/2012/07/building-cc-applications-with-maven/)). However, I don’t want to do that. Could there be an option to call the first two lines shown above from maven to build the `.so` file and then include it with the final `jar`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Apache Hadoop, the build does something similar to what you described. 
 We use the [Apache Maven AntRun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) during the compile phase to make an external call to `cmake` and then call `make` on the build output generated by CMake to compile and link the C portion of our codebase.  This output then feeds into our final build artifacts.  In our case, those build artifacts are tarballs rather than bundled straight into a jar file, but you could accomplish it by controlling configuration of the [Apache Maven JAR Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/index.html).  Specifically, you may need to override content [include/exclude settings](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html).

If you'd like to use it as a starting point, the relevant part of the Hadoop build is visible here:

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.3-RC2/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/pom.xml#L598-L615

```
<execution>
  <id>make</id>
  <phase>compile</phase>
  <goals><goal>run</goal></goals>
  <configuration>
    <target>
      <exec executable="cmake" dir="${project.build.directory}/native" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="${basedir}/src/ -DGENERATED_JAVAH=${project.build.directory}/native/javah -DJVM_ARCH_DATA_MODEL=${sun.arch.data.model} -DREQUIRE_BZIP2=${require.bzip2} -DREQUIRE_SNAPPY=${require.snappy} -DCUSTOM_SNAPPY_PREFIX=${snappy.prefix} -DCUSTOM_SNAPPY_LIB=${snappy.lib} -DCUSTOM_SNAPPY_INCLUDE=${snappy.include} -DREQUIRE_OPENSSL=${require.openssl} -DCUSTOM_OPENSSL_PREFIX=${openssl.prefix} -DCUSTOM_OPENSSL_LIB=${openssl.lib} -DCUSTOM_OPENSSL_INCLUDE=${openssl.include} -DEXTRA_LIBHADOOP_RPATH=${extra.libhadoop.rpath}"/>
      </exec>
      <exec executable="make" dir="${project.build.directory}/native" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="VERBOSE=1"/>
      </exec>
      <!-- The second make is a workaround for HADOOP-9215.  It can
           be removed when version 2.6 of cmake is no longer supported . -->
      <exec executable="make" dir="${project.build.directory}/native" failonerror="true"></exec>
    </target>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: I am able to run cmake build from maven following the idea posted by @Chris Nauroth . Still no luck bundling java class files with with .so .

Comment: @Santanu did you try to bundle your C++ code using swig ? then wrap the "swig/JNI/.so/..." in a maven artifact ?